# Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors using block matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab, generalized-eigenvector

I want to solve numericaly (using Matlab) the generalized eigenvalues-eigenvector equation: $(K-w^2M)q=0$.

Where M and K have the following block structures:

$$ M =  \begin{bmatrix}
M_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ K =  \begin{bmatrix}
K_1 & K_2 \\ K_3 & K_4
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have already resolve it in matlab, but I wanna know if there is a way to save time in this process, because $M$ and $K$ are really big matrices, so I think that I can use the particular form of this matrices to do this.

The problem that I am trying to solve is a band structure, where $w$ is the frequency and $q$ is a displacement of a solid.